# Multiple Condition Coverage

Tags: test-coverage

Trying to figure out the difference between the Multiple Condition Coverage

Code A:

```
if (a && b) then
   print "Hello"
Endif
```

Multiple Condition Coverage for A:

```
a=1 , b=1
a=1 , b=0
a=0 , b=1
a=0 , b=0
```

What about this one?

Code B:

```
if (a) then
   if (b) then
      print "Hello"
   Endif
Endif
```

Does this code have the same "Multiple Condition Coverage"? because when a=0 the inner condition is ignored...

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions effectively do the same thing and do satisfy "multiple condition coverage" assuming you only want "Hello" to print when both are true. Whether or not one is more efficient than the other depends on the language being used. Regardless, both are linear in terms of complexity so for modern languages and hardware the difference is moot.

Comment: Understood, but let's say we need to write a test for Code B which satisfy "multiple condition coverage", do we need to run both cases (a=0, b=1 & a=0, b=0) ?